# What is the expected behavior with Navigation on Cross-Site Publishing? SP2013

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, cross-site-publishing

I have two SharePoint behaviors in my Enviroment

The first one:
Standard Cross-Site Publishing. Authoring catalog has a Metadata Column with Termset A set as Catalog Navigation.
On the publishing site I connected the Catalog (Default Settings - Add Terms to Navigation)

The second one (on a different server):
Standard Cross-Site Publishing. Authoring catalog has a Metadata Column with Termset B set as Catalog Navigation.
On the publishing site I connected the Catalog (Default Settings - Add Terms to Navigation)

If I add a Term to Termset A the term instantly is reused on the publishing site in the Navigation.
In Contrast to that, if I add a Term to Termset B I have to mannually add the new term manually to the Navigation of the Publishing site. For instance via disconnect and reconnect Catalog.

So, what should be the expected behavior with the Navigation on the publishing site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that children of a Top-Level Term are reused automatically but a new Term and all it's children must be added manually. So in order to have a proper Navigation if you want to reuse it from your catalog make sure that the Term-Store is set up on a pretty final version (at least all "top level" Terms should be included there).